# Electron page navigation: Loading content and attached javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, node.js-fs

### I am trying to create a basic page navigation in electron.

In the [electron api demo](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) import is used for that purpose(as far as I can understand it). Regarding the import I found the information that its deprecated and was [removed](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5144752345317376) from Chrome in February 2020.
As an alternative, the **Node-module fs** can be used.
My problem: scripts are not loaded.

**What is the best way to load content and attached javascript into a div?**

Github Code:

Thanks to @Entertain the problem could solved. I have updated the Git-Repo.

Comment: Can you print scripts[i].innerText within the loadPage function and check the output?

Comment: This part gets ignored. <script type="module" src="./winController.js"></script>. Everything inside the second script tags gets printed.

Comment: good question broo

Comment: Why does your home.html also contain a <html> tag? If you load it into index.html you will have two <html> tags which is invalid.

Comment: To further help you, some github repo for investigating would be helpful

Comment: @Entertain I added a repo.

Comment: @Amaroks Thank you, I fixed your project and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first of all, we are working with dynamic DOM elements. This means `addEventListener` is evaluated once and after you add new elements dynamically to your DOM, it won't be applied. This workaround in your `winController.js` will help:

```
// Hello.addEventListener("click", function () {
//   loadPage("./assets/html/Hello.html", "content");
// });

// Info.addEventListener("click", function () {
//   loadPage("./assets/html/Info.html", "content");
// });

// This implementation doesn't care whether an element with the given id exists
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.id == 'Hello') {
    loadPage('./assets/html/Hello.html', 'content');
  } else if (e.target && e.target.id == 'Info') {
    loadPage('./assets/html/Info.html', 'content');
  }
});
```

Next remove the `export` in your `functions.js` file, it's not needed:

```
function thanks() {
  alert('Thanks');
}
```

The only thing left, and that is the most important one, is to update how we load the `functions.js` file dynamically:

```
<!-- <script type="module" src="../js/functions.js"></script> -->
<script type="module">
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = './assets/js/functions.js';
  document.head.append(script);
  
  // function thanks() {
  //     alert("Thanks");
  //   }
  Say.addEventListener('click', function () {
    thanks();
  });
</script>
```

And that's it, after this changes your alert should fire!

**Edit:** Rename your `Hello.Html` to `Hello.html` please, or event better write everything in lowercase in the future to prevent further mistakes: `hello.html` and `info.html`.

**Notice:** In your `Info.html` file your button has the wrong id:

```
<!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-2" id="Info"> -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-2" id="Hello">
  Jump to Hello
</button>
```

Comment: Well, first of all why are you loading winController.js twice in your example? Why not leave it only in the index.html?

Comment: Regarding module scripts you are right, but here you used the eval() function to evaluate

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have limited the home.html to a minimum. Regarding the WinController: If the WinController is not included again, it does not seem to exist in the div (I will update my question)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer. Shouldn't an import be possible here as well? `async function load() {let say = await import("../js/functions.js"); } load();` And can you give me a tip where I can get more information about the dynamic DOM and the function you wrote?